# Lorentz velocity transformations

Tags: special-relativity

I am confused on how to correctly implement Lorentz transformations in various frames.

Let's say I have a stationary observer. A spaceship drives by the observer at 0.75c. The spaceship shoots a bullet backwards at 0.5c in the spaceship's inertial frame.

What speed would the observer observe the bullet going? A Galilean transformation would be .75c - .5c = .25c, but how would I implement the Lorentz transformation here, given the fact that the bullet's speed of .5c is measured in the frame of the spaceship itself?

Additionally, with the opposite approach (the spaceship shoots the bullet straight forward). The Galilean transformation would have the bullet going at 1.25c. Of course the Lorentz transformation is necessary here as well, but again, how would this be implemented?

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: After time $t$ in the ship frame, what are $x,y,z$ of the bullet in that frame? Now transform everything to the observer's frame.

Comment: But since this is linear, you can just use the formula for combining velocities, getting 2c/5 & 10c/11, respectively. But it's good to derive that formula from the transforms.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easiest to step back and derive the velocity transforms from scratch (so that they are general).  Start with the Lorentz transforms for position in spacetime, which are
\begin{align}
ct'&=\gamma(ct-\beta x)\\
x'&=\gamma(x-\beta ct)\\
y'&=y\\
z'&=z
\end{align}
where $(t,x,y,z)$ are the 4 spacetime coordinates for an observer in frame $S$, $(t',x',y',z')$ are the spacetime coordinates for an observer in frame $S'$, which is moving at velocity $v$ along the $x$-axis relative to $S$, $c$ is the speed of light, $\beta = \frac{v}{c}$ and $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta^2}}$ (the Lorentz factor).

These come from the assertion that the speed of light is the same in all frames of reference.  Note that an observer in frame $S'$ (i.e. someone moving at velocity $v$ in relative to frame $S$) will measure different lengths and times according to their own coordinates.

It is valid to consider these in differential form too:
\begin{align}
c\text{d}t'&=\gamma(c\text{d}t-\beta \text{d}x)\\
\text{d}x'&=\gamma(\text{d}x-\beta c\text{d}t)\\
\text{d}y'&=\text{d}y\\
\text{d}z'&=\text{d}z
\end{align}
where note that I have assumed that $v$ is constant (this is the velocity of frame $S'$ according to someone in frame $S$).

Now we bring in some object moving at speed $u$ in frame $S$.  According to an observer in frame $S$, we have
\begin{align}
u_x = \frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}\\
u_y = \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}t}\\
u_z = \frac{\text{d}z}{\text{d}t}
\end{align}
where $(u_x,u_y,u_z)$ are the components of the velocity as measured by someone in frame $S$.  What does an observer in frame $S'$ measure?  Well this is just simply
\begin{align}
u'_x = \frac{\text{d}x'}{\text{d}t'}\\
u'_y = \frac{\text{d}y'}{\text{d}t'}\\
u'_z = \frac{\text{d}z'}{\text{d}t'}
\end{align}
But we can substitute in $(\text{d}t',\text{d}x',\text{d}y',\text{d}z')$ from the position Lorentz transforms above, giving the components of velocity as measured by someone in frame $S'$ (i.e. someone moving at velocity $v$ in frame $S$) to be (with a bit of algebra, and using the fact that $u_i = \text{d}x_i/\text{d}t$):
\begin{align}
u'_x = \frac{u_x-v}{1-\frac{u_xv}{c^2}}\\
u'_y = \frac{u_y}{\gamma\left(1-\frac{u_xv}{c^2}\right)}\\
u'_z = \frac{u_z}{\gamma\left(1-\frac{u_xv}{c^2}\right)}
\end{align}
These are the Lorentz transforms for velocity.  These velocity components $(u'_x,u'_y,u'_z)$ are what an observer moving at velocity $(v,0,0)$ would measure for an object moving at $(u_x,u_y,u_z)$ (both in frame $S$).

Note that to get the inverse transformations, one would have to simply flip the sign of $v$ (think carefully why that might be) and you get
\begin{align}
u_x = \frac{u'_x+v}{1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}}\\
u_y = \frac{u'_y}{\gamma\left(1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}\right)}\\
u_z = \frac{u'_z}{\gamma\left(1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}\right)}
\end{align}

So now let's apply this to your specific problem.  Take the "stationary" observer to be in frame $S$ and the spaceship to be frame $S'$.  We can identify the problem's parameters as follows:
\begin{align}
\text{Spaceship velocity relative to frame $S$}&&&v=0.75c\\
\text{Bullet velocity relative to frame $S'$}&&&u'_x=-0.5c\\
\text{Bullet velocity relative to frame $S$}&&&u_x=?? &\text{(Want to find!)}
\end{align}
Well now that we have the Lorentz transformations, it's easy to find the answer (we need the inverse transformations because we are going from frame $S'$ to $S$):
\begin{align}
u_x=\frac{u'_x+v}{1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}}=\frac{-0.5c+0.75c}{1-0.5\times0.75}=0.4c
\end{align}
If the spaceship shoots the bullet forward, then
\begin{align}
\text{Spaceship velocity relative to frame $S$}&&&v=0.75c\\
\text{Bullet velocity relative to frame $S'$}&&&u'_x=+0.5c\\
\text{Bullet velocity relative to frame $S$}&&&u_x=?? &\text{(Want to find!)}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
u_x=\frac{u'_x+v}{1+\frac{u'_xv}{c^2}}=\frac{+0.5c+0.75c}{1-0.5\times0.75}\approx0.91c
\end{align}
Note of course that if the observer in frame $S$ sees an object travelling slower than $c$, then all other observers measure this object travelling slower than $c$ too (provided of course they are travelling slower than $c$ relative to $S$, which will probably be the case if you're not dealing with weird and wacky tachyons - but that's for a whole other question!)